# Method modifies method out of scope

Tags: java, arrays, theory

i have a very funny issue today. I am trying to modify an array but method modifies another array on which is not even call upon.

a)Part of method which is causing troubles

```
public static void place2(String output, int position,furniture furniture_array[], char room_grid[][]) {

    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    furniture_array[position].setXY(i, j);
    char grid1[][] = room_grid;
    char grid2[][] = room_grid;
    char grid3[][] = room_grid;
    char grid4[][] = room_grid;
    pasteToArray(i, j, grid1, furniture_array[position]);
}
```

b)pasteToArray

This is really simple method which recieves input_array and in this array it will past array which is an object value.

```
public static char[][] pasteToArray(
    int x, int y, char input_array[][], furniture furniture_to_be_placed) {

    char[][] result=input_array;

    for (int i = 0; i <= furniture_to_be_placed.getSize(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= furniture_to_be_placed.getSize(); j++) {
            result[x + i][y + j] = furniture_to_be_placed.furn_grid[i][j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

What is my question?

1. Why the method with input A,B and result C modifies D? ( relative names )

What I've already done to solve it myself: -

1. Debug code - Found a method which is causing problems
2. Helpless cry for 25 minutes includes swearing
3. Checked for global variables
4. Rename all methods inputs to relative neutral names

Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: Don't use underscore('_') while giving name of the method of Java. It's not the convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

grid1, grid2, grid3, and grid4 are all references to the same two-dimensional array. Changing values in one will change values in all.

This code...

```
char grid1[][] = room_grid;
char grid2[][] = room_grid;
char grid3[][] = room_grid;
char grid4[][] = room_grid;
```

does not create 4 copies of room_grid, but rather creates 4 different references to the same block of memory.

Comment: Rather: "create 4 references to the same object with different names" -- Java does not really have a notion of "block of memory", even though the effect is eventually the same.

Comment: So the good resolution would go this way?
int[] b = (int[])a.clone();

Comment: That would work for a one-dimensional array of primatives, but two-dimensional arrays are really just arrays of arrays (i.e. arrays of Objects), meaning `int[][] b = (int[][])a.clone();` would just be producing a copy of the individual references that make up `a`. Likewise, if you are using a one-dimensional array of any other Object type, you would still be creating multiple references to each object, rather than cloning the objects themselves.

Comment: @fge - Can you elaborate on that? Are you just pointing out that a 2d array is just an array of array objects, and as a result does not necessarily form a contiguous block? Or something more than that?

Comment: @Mike an array with elements of type `T` is ultimately a reference to an object of type `T[]`, and that `T` can also be an array, and array elements of `T` may also be arrays etc. Which is why the "reference" is important here: a reference can access an array, it does not embody its elements.